# How to get rid off annoying BEGIN CERTIFICATE from certutil output?

Tags: base64, command-line-tool

I am trying to use certutil with its basic syntax to encode a string that shows me more than what i need. The output of the following

command:

```
certutil -encode pass.txt
```

output:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Z29sZGVuZ2F0ZTEyMw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Please tell me how to use certutil command to get rid off these lines

**-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----**

**-----END CERTIFICATE-----**

OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

`certutil -encode pass.txt | grep -v CERTIFICATE` will work

edit:

grep -v removes lines that matches the regex provided, so this will remove any line containing the phrase "CERTIFICATE"

Comment: I am sorry, i forgot to let you know that i am using windows.

Comment: What is alternate for grep in windows?

Comment: In windows instead of grep you can use findstr. Like : findstr /v CERTIFICATE , add this with a pipe character and you will only see the base64 output

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3rd party b64.exe utility [(7.5 Kb)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/base64/) you can echo the string say on console or redirect to file or transcode files to/from B64

[image]

However there are many ways to use certutil, and by default it adds the 2 `CERTIFICATE-----` lines

So most methods use variations of temporary batch files that strip the --- lines before and after (many of those around these woods)

so for use on one line or in batch files use any variation on this

[image]

```
@certutil -encode -f console.txt console.tmp 1>nul &&type console.tmp|find /v "CERTIFICATE-----">console.txt.b64&&del console.tmp&&type console.txt.b64
```